# How to load .STEP / .STP file in web application for visualization purpose?

Tags: three.js, step

I am trying 3D visualization in web application,currently using three.js. I am able to load .stl file for next phase i want to load .STEP / .STP file but unable to load it, is there is any way ? i have done some research and found that it can be done using pythonOCC but i have no idea about it so please suggest. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done on the front end easily. You probably need a library as big as three.js to process the step files and turn them into a mesh. OCC probably stands for Open Cascade. Which probably does orders of magnitude more than three.js which is a rendering library.

This seems to have some information on the topic, looks like there might be something javascript related if you decide to pursue this.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7125

Comment: Also worth a try: STEP to glTF with cqparts: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/pull/1325